# Where to get posts displaying code in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new to WordPress. From which file posts publishing date and author displaying?

How do we add own css to them. And how do we hide them

[Posts Date & Author Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcCqa.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.If you are using WordPress Default theme,it has an example of the_author in the wp-content/themes/default/index.php but the code is  'commented-out' so it doesn't execute. So if you wanted to display the author info with the WordPress Default theme you would change the line in wp-content/theme/default/index.php

from:

```
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
```

to

```
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?> </small>
```

Note the use of the template tag, the_author_posts_link(), which causes the author's name to be presented as a link to his/her posts.

This also demonstrates the template tag, the_time(), which displays the date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-author-date-and-meta-remover/)
or you can hide by css

```
.entry-author-link { display: none; }
.entry-permalink { display: none; }
.entry-date { display: none; }
.entry-meta { display: none; }
```